# TailwindCSS not working in TypeScript even I already imported

Tags: typescript, tailwind-css

**main.tsx**

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import App from './App.tsx'
import './index.css'
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!).render(
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
)
```

**index.css**

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

**tailwind.config.js**

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  darkMode: ["class"],
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{ts,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{ts,tsx}",
    "./app/**/*.{ts,tsx}",
    "./src/**/*.{ts,tsx}",
  ],
  prefix: "",
  theme: {
    container: {
      center: true,
      padding: "2rem",
      screens: {
        "2xl": "1400px",
      },
    },
    extend: {
      colors: {
        gray900: "#191C1F",
        gray800: "#303639",
        gray700: "#475156",
        gray600: "#5F6C72",
        gray500: "#77878F",
        gray400: "#929FA5",
        gray300: "#ADB7BC",
        gray100: "#E4E7E9",
        gray0: "#fff",
        warning500: "#EBC80C",
        warning400: "#EFD33D",
        warning300: "#f3de6d",
        secondary700: "#1B6392",
        secondary600: "#2484C2",
        secondary500: "#2DA5F3",
        primary500: "#FA8232",
        warning200: "#F7E99E",
        primary100: "#FFE7D6",
        danger600: "#BE4646",
      },
      boxShadow: {
        boxShadow: "0px 1px 0px 0px #303639",
        loginShadow: "0px 8px 40px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12)",
      },
      // colors: {
      //   border: "hsl(var(--border))",
      //   input: "hsl(var(--input))",
      //   ring: "hsl(var(--ring))",
      //   background: "hsl(var(--background))",
      //   foreground: "hsl(var(--foreground))",
      //   primary: {
      //     DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--primary))",
      //     foreground: "hsl(var(--primary-foreground))",
      //   },
      //   secondary: {
      //     DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--secondary))",
      //     foreground: "hsl(var(--secondary-foreground))",
      //   },
      //   destructive: {
      //     DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--destructive))",
      //     foreground: "hsl(var(--destructive-foreground))",
      //   },
      //   muted: {
      //     DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--muted))",
      //     foreground: "hsl(var(--muted-foreground))",
      //   },
      //   accent: {
      //     DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--accent))",
      //     foreground: "hsl(var(--accent-foreground))",
      //   },
      //   popover: {
      //     DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--popover))",
      //     foreground: "hsl(var(--popover-foreground))",
      //   },
      //   card: {
      //     DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--card))",
      //     foreground: "hsl(var(--card-foreground))",
      //   },
      // },
      borderRadius: {
        lg: "var(--radius)",
        md: "calc(var(--radius) - 2px)",
        sm: "calc(var(--radius) - 4px)",
      },
      keyframes: {
        "accordion-down": {
          from: { height: "0" },
          to: { height: "var(--radix-accordion-content-height)" },
        },
        "accordion-up": {
          from: { height: "var(--radix-accordion-content-height)" },
          to: { height: "0" },
        },
      },
      animation: {
        "accordion-down": "accordion-down 0.2s ease-out",
        "accordion-up": "accordion-up 0.2s ease-out",
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [require("tailwindcss-animate")],
};
```

I had already installed tailwind CSS in the app and put `tsx` from the settings but even I imported it still does not work with any classes. I checked clearly that I already imported the required classes so I got stuck. May I ask how to change the settings to have the app working with the classes in tailwind CSS?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you have renamed your entry index.tsx file to main.tsx? It's possible that this is causing the issue, especially if you have executed `npm run eject`. I'm currently unable to recreate the issue in a new react project with your tailwind config.

Comment: Could you also possibly include your App.tsx code and your package.json so I can ensure my project is the same as yours?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure which version your react app is.
BTW, try to modify tailwind.config.js like this:

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{ts,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{ts,tsx}",
    "./app/**/*.{ts,tsx}",
    "./src/**/*.{ts,tsx}",
    "./index.html"(or "./public/index.html")
  ],
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
module.exports = {
  
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{ts,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{ts,tsx}",
    "./app/**/*.{ts,tsx}",
    "./src/**/*.{ts,tsx}",
    "./*.{ts,tsx}", // Include the main.tsx file
  ],
 
};
```

By adding `"./main.ts"` to the `content` array, you're instructing Tailwind CSS to include the `main.ts` file in its analysis for used classes. This ensures that Tailwind CSS will apply styles correctly even if Tailwind classes are used in the `main.ts` file.